# Can't connect to Facebook on 13.10

Tags: firefox, chromium, connection, facebook, hosts

For a few days I haven't been able to connect to Facebook. this is not a browser specific problem because if I ping `www.facebook.com` i get:

```
PING star.c10r.facebook.com (31.13.84.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

I tried browsing with Firefox (main browser) and Chromium just to verify this issue. Both didn't work.

I checked the `/etc/hosts` file and it looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       <my host name>

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and I think this is how it always looked like. I didn't consciously change it. I am able to connect to Facebook from windows on the same machine.

I'm using XUbuntu 13.10.

Comment: Are you under some proxy? Go to the Dash -> Network -> Proxy. What do you see there?

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed it.

I just realized that some other sites where also blocked. incidentally those sites were exactly the sites that a blocked when i tried the self control app. i went to the apps [homepage](http://svn.jklmnop.net/projects/SelfControl.html) and realized that it does create rules for `iptables`. so i just flushed the rules of the `iptables` and everything works just fine now.